# TypeScript sort

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can anyone help me to understand why this sort does not work?

I have created a map to put status priority:

```
this.statusMap = new Map();

this.statusMap.set("Retirando mercadoria", 0);
this.statusMap.set("Em andamento", 1);
this.statusMap.set("Cancelada", 2);
this.statusMap.set("Concluida", 3);
```

My code uses a get on the map to calc on the sort method:

```
console.log(this.deliveriesProgress);
this.deliveriesProgress = this.deliveriesProgress.sort((deliveryA:DeliveryProgress, deliveryB:DeliveryProgress) => {
  let a:number = this.statusMap.get(deliveryA.$tripStatus);
  let b:number = this.statusMap.get(deliveryB.$tripStatus);
  return a - b;
});
console.log(this.deliveriesProgress);
```

After code execute the array printed in console was the same, and i have differents trip status;

[image: The array have some itens and the tripStatus key has different values]

Comment: Can you share the contents of `deliveriesProgress`. My guess is that the map is returning the same value for all tripStatuses.

Comment: I edited the question with an image.

Comment: can you try and show a console log of this.statusMap.get(deliveryA.$tripStatus), i'm suspecting its undefined

Comment: What is the result of using the getter on `$tripStatus`. The sort logic seems find btw.

Comment: when I use the console.log("whatever") inside the sort function, nothing was printed.

Comment: where is $tripStatus defined? do you use any linter?

Comment: I solved the problem, it's really the return of $tripStatus. I called the method inside a promise and the object was not properly completed.